# Using java streams to create new map from existing map

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have a map which is of the following strucutre:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> input;
```

It basically contains, a set of IDs and for each ID, a value associated to an attribute.

```
For ex:
ID:       Attribute    Value
A           X           100
A           Y           200
B           X           40
B           Y           40
```

I am interested only in  the attribute X for each ID and I want to do some processing and store it a new map 
which will have the same defintion Map>

I am trying this in Java 8:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> getResults(Map<String, Map<String, String>> input) {
    input.entrySet().stream()
        .map(id -> {
            String valueX = id.getValue().get("X");
            String computeX = compute(valueX);
            // Now start adding these results to the new map.
        } )
}
```

I am not able to follow, how I can add it to a new map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can collect the entries of the input map into a new map this way:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> getResults(Map<String, Map<String, String>> input) 
{
    return input.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                          e -> {
                                              Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>(); 
                                              map.put("X",e.getValue().get("X")); 
                                              return map;
                                          }));
}
```

- The keys of the output map are the same as the keys of the input map.
- The values of the output map are constructed by creating a new `HashMap<String,String>` and putting in it the value of the `"X"` key.

Comment: I will need to just return input.entrySet() ?

Comment: @user1692342 Oh, answer fixed.

Comment: @user1692342 fixed another typo

Comment: Is a `HashMap` required? `e -> Collections.singletonMap("X", e.getValue().get("X"))` would be much simpler…

Comment: @Holger That's true. I always tend to choose `HashMap` by default, but in this case `singletonMap` seems to make more sense (unless the OP intends to modify these Maps later).